# Will Touchstones be wasted if I touch more than one before death?

Tags: dont-starve

I don't remember if I activated a Touchstone after dying last time, and I found another one. Something tells me that things may go wrong if I have more than 1 Touchstone activated simultaneously.

How do I find out if there is an activated Touchstone?

What happens if there are several Touchstones activated and I get my character killed?

Comment: By the way, it's not a bad idea to drop some grass and logs at a Touchstone.  When you respawn, you'll have no inventory at all, and if it's the middle of winter, you might well freeze and then die a second time before you can get back to your base.  So leave at least enough materials to make a fire.

Comment: I usually leave a chest with a bunch of cool stuff in case that happens.

Comment: Since lives are so rare, a chest is indeed recommended! A lot of people even build a mini-base: chest with grass/twigs/flint/wood, tallbird egg (does not spoil), stone firepit, tools...

Comment: These are some actually really helpful comments.  I'll be using these from now on!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not at all. In general, touch them as soon as you see them.

When you die, you respawn at the closest position available.

So life giving amulet, touch stone or meat effigy.

The only reason not to touch it, is if you got a base besides another respawner, and you'd prefer to respawn there. You risk regretting that when the base is under attack by a giant, it kills you, and you respawn there.